# Alexander subbase theorem proof

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, compactness

I am reading the proof of [Alexanders subbase theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase#Alexander_subbase_theorem) on wikipedia. The proof begins

> Suppose for the sake of contradiction that the space $X$ is not compact (so $X$ is an infinite set), yet every subbasic cover from   $ \ $has a finite subcover. Let ${\displaystyle \mathbb {S} }$  denote the set of all open covers of $X$ that do not have any finite subcover of $X$.

How do we justify the existence of such a set $\mathbb{S}$? I have seen Bertrands paradox before which shows we should not assume that there exists a set of all objects satisfying a particular property. Lets assume we're in ZFC.

Comment: Paradoxes are *usually* named with the surname of someone (often their progenitor, but not always). Bertrand's paradox is something completely different from Russell's paradox, whose first name was indeed Bertrand.

Answer (score 3):

The set of all open covers of $X$ is a subset of $\mathscr P(X)$, so it exists as a set, and since we’re assuming $X$ is not compact, at least one of those open covers must lack a finite subcover.

Answer (score 2):

For a given space $(X, \mathcal T)$

$$\Bbb S= \left\{\mathcal U \in \mathscr{P}(\mathcal T)\mathrel{}\middle|\mathrel{} \bigcup \mathcal U = X \land \left( \forall \mathcal U’ \subseteq \mathcal U \text{ finite } : \bigcup \mathcal U’ \neq X\right)\right\}$$

Is a case of the axiom of comprehension plus power set. (We form a subset of the power set using a property).